# Why are these PNG files different?(originate from same source)

Tags: java, png, response, restlet

In my program, I have a web application that creates a PNG image. This PNG image is written to a file and returned in a request. When I write the request to a file, it is different than the one that was originally written to the harddrive when they should be exactly the same. The PNG from the response is just a blank image. (it is corrupt i guess).

I used a binary diff program to diff the two PNG files and found that some of the characters in the response PNG were just replaced with hexadecimal value 3F instead of their real values.

Here is an image of the diff:
[Diff Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC0JK.png)

It seems as though the response is making some of the HEX values into 3F, why is this? And is there a way to make it stop doing this.

To be more specific about how that response was created, a FileRepresentation (from RESTlet) was used to get the PNG file and put it in a response. I used the RESTlet file type MEDIATYPE_PNG.

Comment: Can you show some code on how the file is being served?

Comment: It would help to know which version of Restlet and connector you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was accessing the response in the wrong way. by using response.getEntity.getText() it does not give an accurate string representation as some of the values from the file are not part of the ascii range. It replaced "?" with those values that are not in the ascii range.

So instead I just got a byte stream by using response.getEntity().getStream() from it and everything works fine.

Thanks all!

Comment: Nothing wrong with adding your own answer and accepting it, but don't neglect to up-vote the other helpful answers, which appear to have been correct.

Comment: Hey all, I remember this question from way back. Glad you got it solved and we were on the right track after all.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern I see here is that in all cases the changed source image bytes are all non-displayable in ASCII and appear to have been replaced by 3F which is ASCII '?', a common character used to replace undisplayable characters.

Answer (score 2):

As karmakaze says, it seems that someone is messing with the encoding, interpreting it as as text file and replacing the 'prohibited' characters by a '?' char. Specifically, the points "corrected" correspond no just to non-ascii points, but to the (few) unused characters in the the [Win-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding (81, 8D, 8F, 90, and 9D). Everything points to someone intepreting a binary content as text, probably in some windows environment.